# Unable to verify the first certificate - ionic app upload error

Tags: node.js, cordova, ssl, ionic-framework, npm

I have developed ionic app and trying to upload it to ionic cloud. I have checked my username and password. Whenever I run `ionic upload` I get an error as:

```
Error logging in: Error: unable to verify the first certificate
Uploading app...

WARN: ionic.project has been renamed to ionic.config.json, please rename it.
An error occurred uploading the build: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
at Object.getDirectUploadKey (C:\Users\jhamn\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\lib\upload.js:271:18)
at C:\Users\jhamn\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\lib\upload.js:41:21
at _fulfilled (C:\Users\jhamn\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\q\q.js:787:54)
at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\jhamn\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\q\q.js:816:30)
at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\jhamn\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\q\q.js:749:13)
at C:\Users\jhamn\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\q\q.js:509:49
at flush (C:\Users\jhamn\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\q\q.js:108:17)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)


Cannot read property 'map' of undefined (CLI v2.2.1)

Your system information:

ordova CLI: 6.5.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Windows 10
Node Version: v6.10.0
Xcode version: Not installed
```

I have already tried setting ssl to false using following command:

```
npm config set strict-ssl false
```

I also came across a possible solution in nodejs through this link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssl-root-cas

But I don't know how to implement a ssl-root-cas in nodejs.